# Find if child inside child data is exist or not Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This may be duplicate Question but i have tries alot but i didnt get my result, Here is my firebase structure

[image: database]

**Updated**

I need to find if the child **expensesName**(For example it can be **oil**) is exists are not under entire node of ***November_2018***(Inside red box).If exists i need to display toast

Below is the Code I have tried:

```
//Here monthyr is the November_2018
      expensesaddref = databaseReference.child(username).child("Expense_Month").child(monthyr);
     //Variable expensesname is the variable that i want to  checked for existent
           expensesaddref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo(expensesname).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       Log.d("List Exp","1 loop");
                       for(DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()){
                           Log.d("List Exp","2 loop");
                               if(data.child("expensesName").exists()){
                                   Log.d("List Exp","if loop");
                                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }else
                               {
                                   Log.d("List Exp","else loop");
                                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }


               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
```

I dont know where iam wrong and it displays **`Not Exist Toast`** always but the firebase has that value

As per **PradyumanDixit Answer** I have updated code but still its not working

```
//Here monthyr is the November_2018
          expensesaddref = databaseReference.child(username).child("Expense_Month").child(monthyr);
expensesaddref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear, if you would just tell more what exactly and which specific nodes do you want to know about, it would be easier to give a precise answer.

Comment: Can you check if `username` has the same unique ID as you intend to have in the image.

Comment: ya its unique i have checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answer **Alex,Aadil,Pradyuman** .As you all suggested i have restructure my query as  **Aadil** mentioned and i can query all my data as required .This is my structure

```
Expense_Month
   |
   --- November_2018
          |
          --- uniqueKey
          |     |
          |     --- expensesName: "gross"
          |     |
          |     --- total: 66
          |     |
          |     --- date_exp: "3_gross"
          |     |
          |     --- current_date: 3

          |
          --- uniquekey
                |
                --- expensesName: "oil"
                |
                --- total: 33
                |
                --- date_exp: "4_oil"
                |
                --- curent_date: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a code like this with `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` to compare all the fields with `expensesName` to a particular value say "oil" and know if such field exists or not.

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Expenses Details").child(uniqueID).child("Expense_Month").child("November_2018");

ref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                              // do what you want here

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { // ToDo: do something about exceptions too

                        }
                  )};
```

Here `uniqueID` is the string that I can see in your database image, between the concerned nodes.

**Edit:**

After staring the structure for a minute, I think I have found the problem. This is not working because you have nodes inside `November_2018` namely `3`, `4` and so on, above the uniqueID node which is above `expensesName`.

This hierarchy is what's causing the problem, I'd advise you to save count inside the uniqeID and not above it, this will make `orderByChild()` work.

As usual with NoSQL databases: if you can't perform the use-case you want with your current data structure, you can typically change/expand your data structure to allow the use-case.

And usually this is done by very directly mapping what you want to show on your screen to the structure in the database.

Your database with dates can look like this:

```json
-UniqueId
|
 -- expensesName
 -- date
 -- total
```

Comment: See My Updated Question. I need to if expensesName under November_2018(Inside Red Box)

Comment: @Gouthami what you want to check is, if the `expensesName` child existing inside the red box, but this gives two options, any of them or all of them?

Comment: any one . For example if i need to check if **oil**  is existed or not under the entire node `November_2018` if yes it should return Toast

Comment: @Gouthami yes, that clears the question, let me write the answer for that.

Comment: ya please help me

Comment: @Gouthami try the updated code and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using right now from my answer, so that I can see where exactly the thing is going wrong.

Comment: But i need to query the the individual date in other prices its bit tough if I change the ds as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I recommend you to change your database structure a little bit. Because there is no way to use in a query dynamic values, or wildcards, you database schema should look like this:

```
Expense_monts
   |
   --- November_2018
          |
          --- -LQ ... Gb
          |     |
          |     --- expensesName: "gross"
          |     |
          |     --- total: 66
          |     |
          |     --- day: "Monday"
          |
          --- -LQ ... LO
                |
                --- expensesName: "oil"
                |
                --- total: 33
                |
                --- day: "Tuesday"
```

As you can see, there is no need to use that extra child (`3`, `4` and so on). In this case, a query that looks like this:

```
expensesaddref = databaseReference.child(username).child("Expense_Month").child(monthyr);
expensesaddref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Will work perfectly fine.

Comment: 3,4 are the dates of current month if i change it its bit more tough for the process

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer in which I have added the `month` as a property of your object. I cannot see another simpler solution for your issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo I think that is date and not month for the OP

Comment: @PradyumanDixit `month: "February"` is a month and not a date.

Comment: @AlexMamo I was referring that OP has November_2018 as the month and those number 3,4,5 as the date of that month.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Oh ya, you're right. Changed from `month` to `day`. Thanks!

Comment: @Gouthami You're welcome. Please also see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gouthami Ok, try it and keep me posted.

Comment: Hi As you all suggested restructured my query .Thank you for your help..your all answers  are helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

As **AlexMamo** said you need to restructure database, i.e to flatten two levels hierarchy to only one level. As shown below:

```
Expense_Month
   |
   --- November_2018
          |
          --- 3_-LQ ... Gb
          |     |
          |     --- expensesName: "gross"
          |     |
          |     --- total: 66
          |     |
          |     --- day: "Monday"
          |     |
          |     --- day: 3
          |
          --- 4_-LQ ... LO
                |
                --- expensesName: "oil"
                |
                --- total: 33
                |
                --- day: "Tuesday"
                |
                --- day: 4
```

Notice each node in **November_2018** is organised by the key formed by *day* followed by *push Id* separated by *underscore*.
i.e "**day_pushId**". You can also add additional field for **day** (incase for particular day query is required). Then the query can be formed in the similar fashion as for "expensesName":

```
//Here monthyr is the November_2018
          expensesaddref = databaseReference.child(username).child("Expense_Month").child(monthyr);
expensesaddref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I will try your structure but how i will query `month:3` only and their total

Comment: It seems to me inside November_2018, you are organising each node according to day, so there is correction in my answer it is according to particular day not month

Comment: In case you want to query for a particular day in a month (say 3rd of November 2018), then the query follows as: `expensesaddref = expensesaddref.orderByChild("day").equalTo(3).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)`.