# how to get value from a text file and link with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a text file containing userPhone and the relevant foodId for recommendation purposes in a menu app.
I have successfully read the relevant foodId based on each userPhone login. How am I able to get the foodId from the text file and retrieve from firebase to display in recycler view? foodId are stored in firebase.
(different user login will display the relevant foodId based on each phone number). I am just a beginner. Thanks in advance

.txt file

```
0122233444=47
0125547890=48
9876543210=54,29,49
```

Recommendation.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recommendation);

    TextView recList = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rec_list);

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    String userPhone = Common.currentUser.getPhone();
    String recommend = findRecommendation(userPhone);

    if (recommend != null) {
        recList.setText(recommend);
    } else {
        recList.setText("Not enough transaction");
    }
}

private String findRecommendation(String userPhone) {

    //open raw resource and connect to input stream variable
    InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.foodrecommendation);

    //scanner
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine(); //phoneNo + foodId
        String [] pieces = line.split("=");
        if (pieces[0].equalsIgnoreCase(userPhone.trim())) {
            return pieces[1];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Firebase structure

[foodId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4hSS.png)

[user phone number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDKjv.png)

Comment: Please be more precise to what you're saying, it's a bit unclear, If you could take an example to tell, it would be better for people to understand.

Comment: why are you keeping phone numbers in a file like that it will unnecessary increase the app size. better you keep eveything in firevase database and get the recommended data for the user

Comment: @PradyumanDixit im storing relevant foodId based on each userPhone which is for recommendation purposes. When the  user login based on their phoneNumbers, the app will only recommend the food found in the textfile based on the userPhone. All foodId are stored in firebase. However, i do not know how to display the only foodId in the text file where can be retrieved from firebase.

Comment: @HarKal i do not know how to store only specific foodId based on each userPhone. Because i already have all foodId in my firebase. So i save in a textfile and read each foodId based on each user login for recommendation purposes in a restaurant menu.

Comment: i have successfully read each relevant foodId based on each user login. But i want to get the foodId by retrieving it from firebase and display in recycler view. Thanks

Comment: So if I get your question correct, @Blue77 you want to retrieve the foodId from firebase and do some operation based on that, for that you need to provide your database structure.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit i have edited my post and attached together with the image of my firebase structure thanks. I just want to get the foodId in the text file and link it with my firebase's food id and display it in my recommendation.java in recyclerView. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The structure you have made is a bit of a problem because, `orderByChild()` won't work on this, to know the reason and how to modify your database structure, have a look at this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153080/8850875

Comment: @PradyumanDixit but i can work this database for other implementation such as displaying favourite list

Comment: i hightly recommend to read the firebase docs and test their examples at least once. and if you have more time make your own test based on the examples they have shown. you will understand eveything