# How to retrieve child data under 2 random keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I display the RequestsID on a recyclerview only when stallID = 1? 
How should my DatabaseReference be?

[image]

update:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @AdrianLoh do mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark button next to the answer and upvote it by clicking on up arrow button. This helps future readers of this question and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your database structure would not support `orderByChild()` from top node. So you would have to set your database reference upto the node `food` and then you can use `orderByChild()` query to find the Childs with certain `stallID`.

This, in code would look something like this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests").child("1542..").child("foods");

  ref.orderByChild("stallID").equalTo(stallIDYouWant).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                 // do here what you wanted
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
                              // ToDo: don't ignore this, do something for errors

                        }
                  )};
```

This would in fact not help you much because you'd have to set this for every unique id in your database structure.

So the better thing to do here would be make your database structure different. To know more how to make your structure good for this operation, refer [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153080/8850875)

Comment: Yes, but make all your unique IDs child node of the node `requests_food` and then you will be able to use `orderByChild()` to query and get those uniqueIDs which have a particular `stallID`

Comment: how about if i want to group the foods under the same node if they are from the same requests? like 'requests_food' -> 'requestID' -> 0 -> { foodID,stallID}, 1-> { foodID,stallID} ?

Comment: No then `orderByChild()` won't work, refer the answer I linked.

Comment: but if i were to follow the table in the first comment, if i want to show the same request only once in a recycler viewholder, how do i do it? cuz if there are 2 foods in a request and the requestsID will be displayed twice

Comment: Can you edit your question with the database structure you're talking about, its hard to understand things like this in comments.

Comment: alright sorry, uploaded the photos. how to display the orderID only once in the recycler view if the orderID is the same? (for '1542779587688')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184249/discussion-between-pradyumandixit-and-adrian-loh).