# Search data in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```java
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference animalsRef = rootRef.child(rootRef.getKey()).child("Personl");
                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Boolean found;
                        String search = editText.getText().toString();
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String movieName = ds.child("firstname").getValue(String.class);
                            found = movieName.contains(search);
                            Log.d("TAG123", movieName + " / " + found);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                };
                animalsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

[I want to search data using child "fullname" and retrieve data under "Persnl" which contains search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSV0t.png)

Comment: I would recommend you to remove the node `Personl` and use `orderByChild()` query to do what you're trying to do, refer this answer and question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153080/8850875

Comment: You are right sir. It works exactly like i want and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of, as also @PradyumanDixit suggested is to remove that extra `Personl` child, so you can query the database according to the `fullname` property. So to solve this, instead of using `animalsRef` reference, please use the following query:

```
Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("fullname").equalTo("Ali Ali");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The rest of your code will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. It works exactly like i want.